# How to migrate old J prefix classes to new Joomla classes

Tags: joomla-3.x, component

I am trying to migrating old classes names to the new ones available on `classmap.php`

However after renaming the classes I am having these errors:

```
Class 'Text' not found //JText works

Class 'BaseController' not found //JControllerLegacy works
```

I am new to joomla but for my understanding I only need joomla 3.x, which I am running.

Am I missing some import?

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour].

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the namespace before you use them, so for your examples above:

```
use \Joomla\CMS\Language\Text;
use \Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController;

class YourClass extends BaseController {
    echo Text::_('YOUR_CONSTANT');
}
```

Otherwise, you can do it like this, which is going to get tedious pretty quick:

```
class YourClass extends \Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController {
    echo \Joomla\CMS\Language\Text::_('YOUR_CONSTANT');
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer. Why Text needs a namespace import while JText does not? I understand it might be defined at root Joomla level, whoever if that's the case why classmap.php isn't aswell?

Comment: `JText` is registered in `classmap.php` which is instantiated by `libraries/cms.php` - required by `/includes/framework.php` which is required by `index.php` - hence you don't need to namespace it in Joomla 3. `Text` needs namespaced because there is no register in `classmap.php` for it until Joomla 4+

Comment: My answer in this thread, https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/27977/easy-way-to-identify-joomla-deprecated-functions/27979#27979, explains how to generate a file that contains all the depreciated class and what Use statement to replace it with. I found it very useful when replacing the J prefix classes. If you are using an IDE then it is even better.